# Convert Encoding.ASCII.GetString to Class Model in C#

Tags: c#, json, class, mqtt

I am trying to encode a 200+ byte-size word payload (Using M2MQTT) into a `Dynamic variable` and thereafter convert the `encoded string (Dynamic variable)` into a JSON object so that it can be mapped to its corresponding Class object so that it can be saved in a SQL Database.

```
//C# 
private void MqttClient_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{
    var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Message);
    JObject? jsonMessage = JObject.Parse(message);
    DataClass? classList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataClass>((string)jsonMessage);
    AddMyItem(classList);
}

public void AddMyItem(DataClass? passedClassList)
{
    using (var context = new DataClassDbContext())
    {
        context.DataClass.Add(passedClassList);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Typical Message Format**

```
[{"sn":1027,"nodeId":"n1","MemberData1":1,"MemberData2":2,"MemberData3":3,"MemberData4":4,"MemberData5":5,"MemberData6":6,"MemberData7":7,"MemberData8":8,"MemberData9":9}]
```

But I am currently stuck at the conversion of `message (Dynamic string variable)` into a `JSON object` in order to pass it to `classList` for Class Model remapping - Not too sure what's the best syntax to implement for this.

The end goal is to map `message`'s member value into a Class object of `DataClass` but of course, there is an implicit conversion type error when trying to pass the values directly, i.e., `vFarm vFarmCo2PdList = message;`. Hence, I am wondering if I need to process `message` variable in some way first.

Comment: Can you explain how you are "stuck"?

Comment: You are parsing the message into json and then cast it back into a string again. It seems to me you kan just ignore that json step and just use the message

Answer (score 0):

Your example message indicated that it's collection of entries of type `DataClass`, which after conversion looks like this:

```
public class DataClass
{
    public int sn { get; set; }
    public string nodeId { get; set; }
    public int MemberData1 { get; set; }
    public int MemberData2 { get; set; }
    public int MemberData3 { get; set; }
    public int MemberData4 { get; set; }
    public int MemberData5 { get; set; }
    public int MemberData6 { get; set; }
    public int MemberData7 { get; set; }
    public int MemberData8 { get; set; }
    public int MemberData9 { get; set; }
}
```

Having said that, you need to try deserializa it to `DataClass[]`, which is array. I also suggest using `System.Text.Json` library, which is already shipped with .NET :)

Also, you do not need to create JObject. just deserialize from string, like this:

```
var o = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DataClass[]>(message);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am trying to do something like this `vFarm vFarmCo2PdListtest = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize < vFarm > message);` so that I can execute `context.DataClass.Add(passedClassList);` in `AddMyItem()`. Currently, if `vFarm[]` is used, I can't execute the SQL ADD command since they are different type, i.e., `vFarm` & `vFarm[]`. Because this is `MVC`, I already have the class declared in the `Model` namespace, which is in fact exactly what you have indicated.

Comment: @Ajax Then just change `public void AddMyItem(DataClass? passedClassList)` to `public void AddMyItem(DataClass[] passedClassList)` and `context.DataClass.Add(passedClassList);` to `context.DataClass.AddRange(passedClassList);`

Comment: Instead of deserializing to an array, try deserializing to a list: `Deserialize<List<DataClass>>(message)`